# JUnit testing for updating object

Tags: java, object, junit

I am try to develop a JUnit test for an update method where it updates the contact information based on the ID. But for some reason it keeps failing. I don't know if the problem lies in the ContactService class or the ContactServiceTest file. Can someone help me with this? Here is my code.

Contact.java

```
package contact;

public class Contact {
    
    // Instance fields
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    
    public Contact(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String phone, String address) {
        if(id == null || id.length()>10) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid id");
        }
        if(firstName == null || firstName.length()>10) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid first name");
        }
        if(lastName == null || lastName.length()>10) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid last name");
        }
        if(phone == null || phone.length()!=10) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid phone number");
        }
        if(address == null || address.length()>30) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid address");
        }
        
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    // Setter firstName
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

}
```

ContactService.java

```
    package contact;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactService {

    Contact contact;
    // Can hold multiple contacts
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Default Constructor
    public ContactService() {
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // Adds contact to our list if the contact is not present.
    public boolean addNewContact(Contact contact) {
        // Determine if the contact is present.
        boolean isPresent = false;
        for (Contact contactList : contacts) {
            if (contactList.getId().equals(contact.getId())) {
                isPresent = true;
            }
        }
        // If the contact is not present then we add contact, then return true.
        if (!isPresent) {
            contacts.add(contact);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If the contact exist in the list, the contact is deleted using contactId
    public boolean deleteExistingContact(String id) {
        for (Contact contactList : contacts) {
            if (contactList.getId().equals(contact.getId())) {
                contacts.remove(contactList);
                return true;

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //
    // Update the contact with the given contactId. If the contact is updated in our
    // list then contact will be firstName, lastName, phoneNumber and address.
    public boolean updateExistingContact(String contactID, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber,
            String address) {
        for (Contact contactList : contacts) {
            if (contactList.getId().equals(contact.getId())) {
                if (!firstName.equals("") && !(firstName.length() > 10)) {
                    contactList.setFirstName(firstName);
                }
                if (!lastName.equals("") && !(lastName.length() > 10)) {
                    contactList.setFirstName(lastName);
                }
                if (!phoneNumber.equals("") && (phoneNumber.length() == 10)) {
                    contactList.setFirstName(phoneNumber);
                }
                if (!address.equals("") && !(address.length() > 30)) {
                    contactList.setFirstName(address);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

ContactServiceTest.java

```
    package test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import contact.Contact;
import contact.ContactService;

class ContactServiceTest {

    @Test
    void testAdding() {
        ContactService contactservice = new ContactService();
        Contact one = new Contact("123456", "Frodo", "Baggins", "2327148686", "42 Shire Street");
        Contact two = new Contact("343499", "Anakin", "Skywalker", "4534235612", "68 Tatooine Court");
        Contact three = new Contact("585858", "Bart", "Simpson", "6123498999", "42 Shire Street");
        assertEquals(true, contactservice.addNewContact(one));
        assertEquals(true, contactservice.addNewContact(two));
        assertEquals(true, contactservice.addNewContact(three));

    }
    
    @Test
    void testDeleting() {
            ContactService contactservice = new ContactService();
            Contact one = new Contact("123456", "Frodo", "Baggins", "2327148686", "42 Shire Street");
            
            contactservice.deleteExistingContact("123456");
            assertEquals(false, contactservice.deleteExistingContact("123456"));
            
        }
    
    @Test
    void testUpdating() {
        ContactService contactservice = new ContactService();
        
        Contact two = new Contact("343499", "Anakin", "Skywalker", "4534235612", "68 Tatooine Court");
        
        
        contactservice.addNewContact(two);
        
        //Test whether contact info with ID 343499 has been updated, which should be true
        assertEquals(true, contactservice.updateExistingContact("343499", "Luke", "Skywalker", "4534235612", "68 Tatooine Court"));
        //Test whether contact info is false, which it should be because 555888 doesn't exist
        assertEquals(false, contactservice.updateExistingContact("555888", "Luke", "Skywalker", "4534235612", "68 Tatooine Court"));
    }
    

}
```

Failure Trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "contact.Contact.getId()" because "this.contact" is null
at contact.ContactService.updateExistingContact(ContactService.java:52)
at test.ContactServiceTest.testUpdating(ContactServiceTest.java:44)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: can you add the error?

Comment: You can set breakpoint and check using debugger, step by step

Comment: this error is on Contact class. Can you add the contact class?

Comment: I added the Contact class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
public class ContactService {

    Contact contact;
    // Can hold multiple contacts
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    public ContactService() {
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

And here:

```
public boolean updateExistingContact(String contactID, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber,
        String address) {
    for (Contact contactList : contacts) {
        if (contactList.getId().equals(contact.getId())) {
```

There's an inconsistency in ContactService class - you assume that it can hold multiple Contact class instances in the `contacts` list and simultaneously declare field `contact` holding just one instance of the Contact class. Then, in the updating method in service class, you are comparing ID of `contact` with IDs of contacts from the list. Also, take a look at the testing method:

```
    @Test
    void testUpdating() {
        ContactService contactservice = new ContactService();
        
        Contact two = new Contact("343499", "Anakin", "Skywalker", "4534235612", "68 Tatooine Court");
        
        
        contactservice.addNewContact(two);
        
        //Test whether contact info with ID 343499 has been updated, which should be true
        assertEquals(true, contactservice.updateExistingContact("343499", "Luke", "Skywalker", "4534235612", "68 Tatooine Court"));
        //Test whether contact info is false, which it should be because 555888 doesn't exist
        assertEquals(false, contactservice.updateExistingContact("555888", "Luke", "Skywalker", "4534235612", "68 Tatooine Court"));
    }
```

You are never assigning any value to the `contact` field, so it is null. Then, you try to call `getId()` on the null value, which cause that NPE.